# retrieve the history of the contents variables after the execution with option -DDEBUG_HISTORY in C

Tags: c

I need to save the compilation history of a program run several times, to follow the change of variables after each execution.
without doing any printf.

i need a way like that, but i want the values to be saved in a log file and not display in the console.

```
#include "stdio.h"

int a = 1;
int b = 1;

#if DEBUG_HISTORY
int * pa = &a;
int * pb = &b;

#define a printf("a = %d\n", a); (*pa)
#define b printf("b = %d\n", b); (*pb)
#endif

int main()
{
int i;

 for (i=1; i<4; i++)
 {

  a += i;

  b *= i;
}
}
```

Compile with option -DDEBUG_HISTORY and get:

```
 a = 1

 b = 1

 a = 2

 b = 1

 a = 4

 b = 2
```

there is someone who can help me please, to change the program so that the value is saved in a separate file.

Comment: what has "compilation history of a program" to do with "of a program run several times"?

Comment: On linux you can use `myprog > log.txt` to capture the output in file `log.txt`

Comment: i am working on windows on eclipse as i can do in this case please?